# Css :before add text on top without affecting div height

Tags: css

I am trying to mark some `div.ad` containers with a label on the top so that visitors to a website knows that the container contains ads.

However, sometimes ads might not be served, and the container will have an height of 0px. So that it does not affect the view of the page.

I tried this:

```
.ad:before {
content: "This is an ad";
display:block;
font-size:10px;
}
```

However, this ads about 10-12 px to the container no matter if it has content or not. So when the .ad container is 0px, its still renders the :before.

I also tried:

```
.ad:before {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
content: "This is an ad";
}
```

That works to a point. It does not show when the .ad container is 0px high, but when it actually contains and ad, the ad is rendered over the text. Is there any way to implement that last solution, in such a fassion that it is only shown when the .ad container is larger than 0px of height, and so that it pushes the content of .ad down the same amount of px as the content I add to the :before?

Comment: `:before` will be visible as long as .ad section is *visibile* in your page, despite of the fact there is content in .ad or not.

Comment: instead use this `.ad:not(:empty):before` to check if the `element` is `:empty` and add the text http://jsfiddle.net/c5e79m5x/

Comment: That wont work @Vitorinofernandes. Google populates the container with elements even if no ad is shown. If it wasnt for that It would work. However, I accepted an answer below, but due to responsivness I didnt go for it because it could place the :before content on top of something else. Instead I added a margin-top to any iframe-element inside .ad. Because its only populated with iframes when an ad is actually served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use z-index to insure that the pseudo element always appear on top of anything inside .ad container. this will require setting the content to z-index that is lower than the pseudo element like that:

```
.ad:before {
position: absolute;
top:-14px;
left:0;
font-size:14px;
content: "This is an ad";
z-index:2;
}
.ad,.ad * {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/35gh307r/

Comment: Yep, I thought of this. But that would mean that the text "This is an ad" would be placed in the actualy view port of the ad, and thats not a good solution, since the ad might be of a black background and the text would be black for example. I need the text above the actual content rendered inside the .ad container

Comment: you can set a negative top position to grab the text above the ad content. I edited the solution

Comment: You're right. Its an acceptable answer. I didnt choose it in my scenario, but it would have done the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add some padding-top to the .ad container, this way even if there is no content the container will still have the same padding.

I've edited the fiddle of `@Heidar`

https://jsfiddle.net/35gh307r/2/